# Is plotly:plotlyOutput interchangeable with shiny::plotOutput?

Tags: r, shiny, r-plotly

```
.dev_triangle_diag_main <- shiny::mainPanel(
  shiny::fluidRow(
           shiny::column(width=6, shiny::plotOutput("diag_year")),
           shiny::column(width=6, shiny::plotOutput("diag_cal_year"))),
  shiny::fluidRow(
           shiny::column(width=6, shiny::plotOutput("diag_value")),
           shiny::column(width=6, shiny::plotOutput("diag_dev_month"))))
```

In the above snippet, wherever there is "shiny::plotOutput" it used to be "plotly::plotlyOutput".

It worked as expected when it was "plotly::plotlyOutput", but after switching to "shiny::plotOutput" the page became blank.

Comment: Probably not, Plotly is an external program.

Comment: Plotly is an external package as pointed out. Also a plotOutput in the ui needs to be accompanied by a renderPlot() call in the server. Similarly a renderPlotly for a plotlyOutput call.